# How can I use QWindow features (eg. startSystemMove) with a QWidget to make a custom titlebar?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to use `startSystemMove` and `startSystemResize` [described here](https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations) to give my PyQt5 GUI a custom titlebar, but my project uses `QWidget` and these methods only exist on `QWindow`. Is it possible for me to wrap my `QWidget` inside a `QWindow` or if not, are there any equivalent methods for `QWidget`?

From what I read in other StackOverflow posts it sounded like custom titlebars required manually reimplementing all system resize behavior, but I am wondering if now with Qt 5.15 there is a better way that will work with QWidgets

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do but... you can always get the `QWindow` associated with a top-level widget using [`QWidget::windowHandle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowHandle).

Comment: @G.M. That's exactly what I was struggling to find, thank you!